# Getting date from html tag using regular expression in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to get the date from

```
XXX='<div class="document-published-date">
                                July 14, 2018
                            </div>'
```

I was expecting that something like this would work

```
re.search('>(.*?)</div>',XXX)
```

but I am getting an empty result.

Comment: either `re.findall('>\s*(.*?)\s*</div>',XXX,re.S)` but it will be better if you use the corresponding packages

Comment: I think there should not an `]` at the end of the regex

Comment: Yes, thanks. It worked, but it comes with some garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, dot does not match new line. You need to use (?s) flag to enable dot to match new line. Also you need to slightly correct your regex (remove `]` at the end of your regex '>(.*?)]') like this,

```
(?s)>\s*(.*?)\s*</div>
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)` --> Enables dot to match new lines
- `>` --> Matches > character literally
- `\s*` --> Consumes any whitespace before intended text capture
- `(.*?)` --> Capture your intended data
- `\s*` --> Capture any whitespace after intended data
- `</div>` --> Matches this tag

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/thj2Wf/1)

Comment: I really appreciate the carefully explanation and also the site "regex"!

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Answer (score -1):

It's probably [not a good idea to use regexes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions) like this on a regular basis. You could instead use a module like [htmldate](https://github.com/adbar/htmldate) to do extract the date of HTML documents *(disclaimer: I'm the author)*, here is how it could work:

**1. Install the package:**

```
pip/pip3/pipenv (your choice) -U htmldate
```

**2. Retrieve a web page, parse it and output the date:**

```
from htmldate import find_date

find_date('http://blog.python.org/2016/12/python-360-is-now-available.html')
```